# Samsung USB not showing in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: usb, android, 18.04

Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't recognize any of my Android devices.

When I type `lsusb` it not showing any mobile devices.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Connect to a Samsung Android phone via USB in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

It works for me to see the Android via USB in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, after

- connecting the Android device (a Samsung mobile phone)
- *logging into Android and allowing the computer to see it*. I am prompted with a question about it directly after logging in. (I use Android 7.1.1, and you may have to look for a menu item to allow the computer to see it in older versions of Android.)
- Now the file browser `nautilus` in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS can browse the content of the mobile phone.
- `lsusb` can also list it.

See the attached screenshot

[image]

Comment: "I am prompted with a question about it directly after logging in." - That doesn't help in cases where nothing's happening.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, I understand that there can be problems. Maybe your phone or its version of operating system is not fully compatible with Ubuntu. (This answer is 'only' describing the standard case, and it is not a debugging manual. I think you can get better help, if you start a thread at the [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org), where more discussions and extended dialogues are encouraged (compared to AskUbuntu)).

Answer (score 7):

I tried to install mtp , terminal says libmtp is the newest version and finally this [answer worked for me](https://askubuntu.com/a/1038233/745465).

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0BB4A1B2FA1A38EB
$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/samoilov-lex/aftl-stable/ubuntu artful main"
$ sudo apt-get install android-file-transfer
```

Comment: Wow, I've tried many things with Ubunt 18.06 and Samsung A3 and this is the only trick that worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: This seemed to work, then stop working again.

Answer (score 2):

I went to Developer options on my phone and then I only press Revoke USB debugging aut...
and It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and after I cleaned the USB-C port and the USB port on my laptop, it managed to solve it. Try it. Yes I know, that's a frustratingly simple answer, but it could still be the answer. I was floored when I figured it out myself.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo he resuelto simplemente con otro cable usb. El cable tiene serigrafiado la siguiente información:
usb 2.0
cable awm 2725 vw-1 80ºC 30V
Yo tengo xubuntu 20.04 lts y galaxy tab10 2016

I have solved it simply with another usb cable. The cable has the following information printed on it:
usb 2.0
cable awm 2725 vw-1 80ºC 30V
I have xubuntu 20.04 lts and galaxy tab10 2016

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about your situation, but a guy on the web said just plug in your USB cable, then go into your phone settings screen and type the search word "**USB**", then enable "**USB tethering**". That's all.