# Trying to install android-file-transfer Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic

Tags: package-management, software-installation, ppa

I followed the procedure explained [in the main PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~samoilov-lex/+archive/ubuntu/aftl-stable):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:samoilov-lex/aftl-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install android-file-transfer
```

and I received this message after use:

```
sudo apt-get install android-file-transfer

E: Unable to locate package android-file-transfer
```

Comment: The usb cable has the advantage of using your PC to access your Android phone as an external drive. But, if you wish to transfer files via the wireless lan, you need 2 applications: Filezilla for the PC from the repositories; and FTP ServerPlus for the phone get it from googleplay. Once installed, the procedure is to read the settings from FTPseverPlus on phone, and enter them into Filezilla at the top of the screen on PC. The data you need are: ftp address; port; username; password. [on phone, set anonymous to off]. Use Filezilla to control the transfers. Pros are speed and large files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a problem with the packaging of the PPA for **Bionic**. You can instead use **Artful** PPA to install **Android File Transfer** on Ubuntu 18.04. (Same version, 3.2-1 as of the time of writing)

First add the PPA to your sources:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0BB4A1B2FA1A38EB
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/samoilov-lex/aftl-stable/ubuntu artful main"
```

Make sure to run a `sudo apt update` to load the new packages, then install `android-file-transfer` the usual way:

```
sudo apt install android-file-transfer
```

Comment: Working fine in Xubuntu 18.04 x386, only you have put first the key because give error to install it, but first add the key, next add repository, next install working fine all. Very thanks because my Galaxy J5 not woring fine MTP protocol with Nautilus

Comment: @Indacochea Not sure why adding the repository before the key didn't work for you, but I switched their order anyway. You're welcome

Comment: Executing    sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0BB4A1B2FA1A38EB   got the following error:   Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.Eomyetg9Ew/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0BB4A1B2FA1A38EB  
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure

Answer (score 7):

The following steps were required before I finally got this to run:

1. Plug in phone via USB cable.
2. (on Android device) yes allow access.
3. (on Ubuntu) click 'eject' to unmount the Nautilus (file explorer) automount of the device.
4. Run `sudo pkill mtp`
5. Run `android-file-transfer`

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting issue to install android file transfer on kubuntu 18.04. At last I find best solution appimage base, and its work for me. I am sharing link appimage link

https://github.com/whoozle/android-file-transfer-linux/releases/download/v3.7/Android_File_Transfer-5bf7652-x86_64.AppImage

It will work. We only have to change permission

```
sudo chmod +x Android_File_Transfer-5bf7652-x86_64.AppImage
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a problem - can't run this app. It shows first a window with msg

"Device is busy, maybe another process is using it.

The following processes are keeping file descriptors for your device:
/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-mtp (pid: 13865)
Close other MTP applications and restart Android File Transfer.

Press Abort to kill them or Ignore to try next device."

If Ignore presed, it returns "No MTP Device found"

Aborting doesn't work - it returns msg

"Device locked..."